# Does anyone know what the new Exit icon is used for when editing storyboards using Xcode 4.5?

Tags: interface-builder, ios6, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, xcode4.5

Right-clicking the Exit icon yields an empty window. Can't Ctrl-drag a connection to any IB elements or corresponding source files. Docs give no love. Doesn't appear in nib files, only storyboards. My assumption is that it's a corollary to segues, but I don't see any new methods to back it up. Anyone?

Comment: Dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416050/xcode-4-5-storyboard-exit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.5 Storyboard 'Exit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416050/xcode-4-5-storyboard-exit)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There's a lot of information in the WWDC video "Session 407 - Adopting Storyboards in your App."

Say you have two view controllers linked by a segue. Implement the following exit action on the first view controller:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Popping back to this view controller!");
    // reset UI elements etc here
}
```

Then, on Storyboard scene for the second view controller, Ctrl-drag from a UI element, such as a button, to the exit icon at the bottom of this view controller. The `done:` action you added to the code of the first controller will appear as an option. Now, activating the button you Ctrl-dragged to the exit icon will pop back to the first view controller and maintain its original state (ie UI elements such as text input supposedly still intact).

Comment: It actually unwinds back to the exact same instance of the view controller (and its views).

Comment: Thanks, I was reading this just to learn what the "Green Exit" was about, only to find out it resolve a problem for me.  I had 2 view controllers separated by a TabBar controller and a navigation controller, and "Pop" didn't work to return backwards. This took 2 minutes and everything worked as you said!  THANKS!

Comment: How can I invoke action method on `Done` button in class of view B before exiting back to view A ?

Comment: If you watch the WWDC video you can skip to 37:15 to see the part about "unwind segues"

Answer (score 222):

I had a hard time following the accepted answer so here is more detail.

Given the photo below on view controller C you can "exit" back to any view controller in the segue path.

[image]

ViewController **A** you can write:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    // Optional place to read data from closing controller
}
```

ViewController **B** you can write:

```
- (IBAction)back:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    // Optional place to read data from closing controller
}
```

ViewController **C** you control drag from **"back"** button to the green exit option and select **back:**
ViewController **C** you control drag from **"done"** button to the green exit option and select **done:**
[image]

Note: Even though the methods are on other view controllers they show up for the ViewController **C**'s exit. **Control dragging and selecting a method defines which ViewController to unwind to.**

Comment: One more note: sometimes green exit button not being active even all steps are done. In this case reopening storyboard (or xcode project) makes it work as expected.

Comment: Another issue I had was that I didn't put my unwind segue method signature in my .h file or class extension. After I added it the unwind segue showed up in the popup.

Comment: +Infinity for `Even though the methods are on other view controllers they show up for the ViewController C's exit.`

Answer (score 15):

As addition to [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052616/eric) answer here is how it works with [swift](/questions/tagged/swift):

The function you add to the destination controller looks like:

```
@IBAction func backFromOtherController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    NSLog("I'm back from other controller!")
}
```