# Workaround for swift unwinding

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue, swift

So in response to this question:
[Xcode 6 Storyboard Unwind Segue with Swift Not Connecting to Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029586/xcode-6-storyboard-unwind-segue-with-swift-not-connecting-to-exit)

I'm having the same problem and tried the fix presented, but it still doesn't work. I get the feeling that I'm missing a step for my header file, is it sufficient to simple add a .h file to my project and add the lines mentioned? Or is there more to it?

IndexViewController.h:

```
@interface IndexViewController (Workaround)
- (IBAction)blaat: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end
```

IndexViewController.swift:

```
@objc(IndexViewController) class IndexViewController : UITableViewController {
@IBAction func blaat(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
    println("Test");
} 
}
```

Edit1: I do complete step 3, which is to unset and re-set the custom class for the instance of IndexViewController in the StoryBoard

Edit2: Fixed it, the issue was indeed in the header. IndexViewController.h should be:

```
@class IndexViewController;
@interface IndexViewController : UITableViewController
- (IBAction)unwindToIndexViewController: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing step 3: clear view controller class in IB inspector and set it back.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode6-Beta 4 this bug has been fixed. I tried it myself in one of my project. Upgrade your xcode and you can forget the workaround.