# How to create a login/signin iOS screen like Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, rubymotion

I'm trying to get a behavior similar to the Parse login/signup screen.

**Scenario**
Their `LoginController` is presented as a modal. It has a button named `signup`, which when pressed, shows the `signup` screen as another modal with the `close` button. `close` button lets the user go back to the login screen and when the user signs up it takes the user back to main screen.

I have everything working so far with only one problem.

**Question**

How do I direct the user back to `MainController` after he signs up on the `SignController`?

**What I've done so far**

This is what I have so far, however, I'm not able to redirect the user to `MainController` after they signup successfully.

AppDelegate.rb

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    @window.rootViewController = MainController.alloc.init
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end
```

MainController.rb

```
class MainController < UIViewController

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    @sessionId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults
    if @sessionId["token"] == nil
      login = LoginController.alloc.init
      login.delegate = self
      self.presentViewController(login, animated:true, completion:nil)
    end
  end

  def logged_in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated true, completion:nil
  end

end
```

LoginController.rb

```
class LoginController < UIViewController

  attr_accessor :delegate

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    # show username/pwd
    # show button for login
    # show button for signup
  end

  def press_login_button
    delegate.logged_in
  end

  def press_signup_button
    signup = SignupController.alloc.init
    signup.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(signup, animated:true, completion:nil)
  end

  def signed_up
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated true, completion:nil #close signup screen
    delegate.logged_in #close login screen
  end
end
```

SignupController.rb

```
class SignupController < UIViewController

  attr_accessor :delegate

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    # show username/pwd
    # show button for close
    # show button for signup
  end

  def press_close_button
    #go back to login controller. how?
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated true, completion: nil
  end

  def press_signup_button
    delegate.signed_up
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be accomplished by separating concerns a little bit more here - in particular, note that the Signup and Login controllers both assume they were presented modally.  Instead, have them ask their delegate to handle the showing/hiding.

```
# from login/signup controller
delegate.should_hide(self)

# from main controller
def should_hide(controller)
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
end
```

And here's the answer to your question

```
# from signup controller
def should_hide(controller)
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: -> do
    delegate.should_hide(self)
  end)
end
```

This will hide each window *one at a time*, which you might not want... if you want to hide *both* windows at the same time, try this:

```
# from signup controller
def should_hide(controller)
  # this will ask the main controller to hide the presented controller...
  # and BOTH controllers will hide at the same time!
  delegate.should_hide(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to provide you ruby code to demonstrate, but what you are looking for is called an exit or unwind segue.  If you are targeting IOS 6 or later you can use the functionality.

on the controller you are going to exit to you need to setup a method to unwind.  It would look something like this in objc, and then you call this from the controller you are exiting from:

```
- (IBAction)myExitSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender {


}
```

Here is a link to more info on this:
http://www.freelancemadscience.com/fmslabs_blog/2012/9/24/advanced-storyboard-techniques.html

you can also check this stack overflow question here: 
[Xcode 4.5 Storyboard 'Exit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416050/xcode-4-5-storyboard-exit)

hope that helps.